# sql insert from table to table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table `Farm` with these columns

```
FarmID:(primary)
Kenizy:
BarBedo:
BarBodo:
MorKodo:
```

These columns are palm types in some language. each column of those contains a number indicates the number of this type of palm inside a farm.

Example:

```
FarmID  | Kenizy  | BarBedo | BarBodo | MorKodo
-----------------------------------------------
3       |   20    |   12    |   45    |   60
22      |   21    |    9    |    41   |   3
```

I want to insert that table into the following tables:

Table `Palm_Farm`

```
FarmID:(primary)
PalmID;(primary)
PalmTypeName:
Count:
```

That table connects each farm with each palm type.

Example:

```
FarmID   |   PalmID   |  PalmTypeName   |  Count
-----------------------------------------------
   3     |     1      |      Kenizy     |   20
   3     |     2      |    BarBedo      |  12
   3     |     3      |     BarBodo     |  45
   3     |     4      |     MorKodo     |  60
  22     |     1      |     Kenizy      |  21
  22     |     2      |     BarBedo     |  9
  22     |     3      |     BarBodo    |   41
  22     |     4      |     MorKodo    |   3
```

I have to use the following table `Palms` in order to take the `PalmID` column.

```
PalmID:(primary)
PlamTypeName:
...other not important columns
```

This table is to save information about each palm type.

Example:

```
PalmID  |    PlamTypeName 
-------------------------
   1    |  Kenizy     
   2    |  BarBedo     
   3    |  BarBodo       
   4    |  MorKodo
```

The `PalmTypeName` column has the value the same as the **COLUMN NAMES** in the `Farm` table.

So my question is:

How to insert the data from `Farm` table to `Palm_Farm` considering that the PalmID exist in the `Palm` table

I hope I could make my question clear, I tried to solve my problem myself but the fact that the **column name** in the `Farm` table must be the `column value` in the `Palm_Farm` table couldn't know how to do it.

I can't change the table structure because we are trying to help a customer with this already existing tables

I am using SQL Server 2008 so `Merge` is welcomed.

#### Update

After the genius answer by `@GarethD`, I got this exception

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [UNPIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to turn the columns into rows:

```
INSERT Palm_Farm (FarmID, PalmID, PalmTypeName, [Count])
SELECT  upvt.FarmID,
        p.PalmID,
        p.PalmTypeName,
        upvt.[Count]
FROM    Farm AS f
        UNPIVOT
        (   [Count]
            FOR PalmTypeName IN ([Kenizy], [BarBedo], [BarBodo], [MorKodo])
        ) AS upvt
        INNER JOIN Palms AS p
            ON p.PalmTypeName = upvt.PalmTypeName;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2272b2/1)**

The docs for `UNPIVOT` state:

> UNPIVOT performs almost the reverse operation of PIVOT, by rotating columns into rows. Suppose the table produced in the previous example is stored in the database as pvt, and you want to rotate the column identifiers Emp1, Emp2, Emp3, Emp4, and Emp5 into row values that correspond to a particular vendor. This means that you must identify two additional columns. The column that will contain the column values that you are rotating (Emp1, Emp2,...) will be called Employee, and the column that will hold the values that currently reside under the columns being rotated will be called Orders. These columns correspond to the pivot_column and value_column, respectively, in the Transact-SQL definition.

To explain further how unpivot works, I will look at the first row original table:

```
FarmID  | Kenizy  | BarBedo | BarBodo | MorKodo
-----------------------------------------------
3       |   20    |   12    |   45    |   60
```

So what UPIVOT will do is look for columns specified in the `UNPIVOT` statement, and create a row for each column:

```
SELECT  upvt.FarmID, upvt.PalmTypeName, upvt.[Count]
FROM    Farm AS f
        UNPIVOT
        (   [Count]
            FOR PalmTypeName IN ([Kenizy], [BarBedo])
        ) AS upvt;
```

So here you are saying, for every row find the columns `[Kenizy]` and `[BarBedo]` and create a row for each, then for each of these rows create a new column called `PalmTypeName` that will contain the column name used, then put the value of that column into a new column called [Count]. Giving a result of:

```
FarmID  | Kenizy  | Count |
---------------------------
3       | Kenizy  |  20   | 
3       | BarBedo |  12   |
```

---

If you are running SQL Server 2000, or a later version with a lower compatibility level, then you may need to use a different query:

```
INSERT Palm_Farm (FarmID, PalmID, PalmTypeName, [Count])
SELECT  f.FarmID,
        p.PalmID,
        p.PalmTypeName,
        [Count] = CASE upvt.PalmTypeName
                    WHEN 'Kenizy' THEN f.Kenizy
                    WHEN 'BarBedo' THEN f.BarBedo
                    WHEN 'BarBodo' THEN f.BarBodo
                    WHEN 'MorKodo' THEN f.MorKodo
                END
FROM    Farm AS f
        CROSS JOIN
        (   SELECT  PalmTypeName = 'Kenizy' UNION ALL
            SELECT  PalmTypeName = 'BarBedo' UNION ALL
            SELECT  PalmTypeName = 'BarBodo' UNION ALL
            SELECT  PalmTypeName = 'MorKodo'
        ) AS upvt
        INNER JOIN Palms AS p
            ON p.PalmTypeName = upvt.PalmTypeName;
```

This is similar, but you have to create the additional rows yourself using `UNION ALL` inside the subquery `upvt`, then choose the value for `[Count]` using a case expression.

---

To update when the row exists you can use MERGE

```
WITH Data AS
(   SELECT  upvt.FarmID,
            p.PalmID,
            p.PalmTypeName,
            upvt.[Count]
    FROM    Farm AS f
            UNPIVOT
            (   [Count]
                FOR PalmTypeName IN ([Kenizy], [BarBedo], [BarBodo], [MorKodo])
            ) AS upvt
            INNER JOIN Palms AS p
                ON p.PalmTypeName = upvt.PalmTypeName
)
MERGE Palm_Farm WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS pf
USING Data AS d
    ON d.FarmID = pf.FarmID
    AND d.PalmID = pf.PalmID
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
    INSERT (FarmID, PalmID, PalmTypeName, [Count])
    VALUES (d.FarmID, d.PalmID, d.PalmTypeName, d.[Count])
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE
    SET [Count] = d.[Count],
        PalmTypeName = d.PalmTypeName;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is my first time I see SQL Fiddle, so where can I see the results please?

Comment: I couldn't understand a word you wrote :) could you explain your code a little bit please??

Comment: +1 for you but I am still trying to understand your code, I am searching online about the `UPIVOT` It may take  me some time to understand it, many thanks

Comment: Have you read through the online docs in the link in the answer? I think the explanation in there is better than any I could provide (Having just tried and failed to write a decent explanation).

Comment: yes I am reading into it now, but the problem that the link you provide is not on the white list of my company's newtwork so I am reading it through a mobile with small screen :) don't worry I will continue reading and appreciate your help and efforts with me

Comment: wow great description, I just updated the qeustion with the error I got, could you check please. if that error is a syntax error or something bigger?

Comment: Are you sure you are running on SQL Server 2008? What is the result of the following query: `SELECT compatibility_level, [Version] = @@VERSION FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'Your Database Name'`

Comment: I got `80`, `Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1617.0 (X64)   Apr 22 2011 19:23:43   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition with Advanced Services (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) `

Comment: Your database is set to the SQL Server 2000 [compatibility level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb510680.aspx), you either need to use the second solution I posted, or alter the database to use a more current compatibility level - `ALTER DATABASE database_name SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100`

Comment: it seems that alter the compatibility is easier. I will try it and update u

Comment: I changed the compatibility level and the error goes but I got another error. First is the compatibility affects anything else? to tell you about the new error, I put fake names in the question becuase of the privacy of my company, so in your  `SELECT  upvt.FarmID,p.PalmID,` to which table does the `FarmID` and `PalmID` belongs?

Comment: I guess the error goes :) let me try to insert and will update you

Comment: aren't you the sweetest guy in the world . everything works perfectly 1000000000000000000 thanks

Comment: you don't know how much I am thankful and grateful to you. you the one.

Comment: you know what, just last thing please, you make always select is there a way to update the `Palm_Farm` when the `PalmID` and the `FarmID` exists?